# Where can I ask for software by describing what it should do?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask for software or software components by describing what they should do?

For example:

> Q: I'm searching for a server that stores data structures and has a python client
>
> A: [Redis](http://redis.io) can do this, there is a [redis python client](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/)

I'm not sure if this kind of question is considered a [shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) since there are often multiple possibilities. The goal of this question should better be to **find one software or software component that does the job**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Be sure to [provide enough information](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)